# Linux Text File Manipulation

Tags: linux, text, awk, sed

I have a file of the format:

```
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Superior Mana Oil">  
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tabard of Brute Force">  
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tabard of the Wyrmrest Accord">  
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tattered Hexcloth Sack">
```

I need to select the text after the = but before the " and print this at the end of the line, adding  so it becomes for example:

```
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Superior Mana Oil">Superior Mana Oil</a>  
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tabard of Brute Force">Tabard of Brute Force</a>  
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tabard of the Wyrmrest Accord">Tabard of the   Wyrmrest Accord</a>  
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tattered Hexcloth Sack">Tattered Hexcloth Sack</a>
```

I'm not sure of the best way to do this via linux command line (I guess probably sed/awk but not good with them), would ideally like a script I can just feed the filename e.g. ./fixlink.sh brokenlinks.txt

Comment: Try to write the script and run it. When/If you get errors, post them here and help will be available. "Please write my scripts for me" type questions aren't very encouraged here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can have one or more space afer `<a`, and zero or more space around the `=` signs, the following should work:

```
$ cat in.txt
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Superior Mana Oil">
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tabard of Brute Force">
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tabard of the Wyrmrest Accord">
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tattered Hexcloth Sack">
#
# The command to do the substitution
#
$ sed -e 's#<a[ \t][ \t]*href[ \t]*=[ \t]*".*search[ \t]*=[ \t]*\([^"]*\)">#&\1</a>#' in.txt
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Superior Mana Oil">Superior Mana Oil</a>
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tabard of Brute Force">Tabard of Brute Force</a>
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tabard of the Wyrmrest Accord">Tabard of the Wyrmrest Accord</a>
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tattered Hexcloth Sack">Tattered Hexcloth Sack</a>
```

If you're sure you don't have the extra spaces, the pattern simplifies to:

```
s#<a href=".*search=\([^"]*\)">#&\1</a>#
```

In `sed`, `s` followed by any character (`#` in this case) starts substitution.  The pattern to be substituted is until the second appearance of the same character.  So, in our second example, the pattern to be substituted is: `<a href=".*search=\([^"]*\)">`.  I used `\([^"]*\)` to mean, any sequence of non-`"` characters, and saved it in backreference `\1` (the `\(\)` pair denotes a backreference).  Finally, the next token delimited by `#` is the replacement.  `&` in `sed` stands for "whatever matched", which in this case is the whole line, and `\1` just matches the link text.

Here's the pattern again:

```
's#<a[ \t][ \t]*href[ \t]*=[ \t]*".*search[ \t]*=[ \t]*\([^"]*\)">#&\1</a>#'
```

and its explanation:

```
'                       quote so as to avoid shell interpreting the characters
s                       substitute
#                       delimiter
<a[ \t][ \t]*           <a followed by one or more whitespace
href[ \t][ \t]*=[ \t]*  href followed by optional space, = followed by optional space
".*search[ \t]*=[ \t]*  " followed by as many characters as needed, followed by
                        search, optional space, =, followed by optional space
\([^"]*\)               a sequence of non-" characters, saved in \1
">                      followed by ">
#                       delimiter, replacement pattern starts
&\1                     the matched pattern, followed by backreference \1.
</a>                    end the </a> tag
#                       end delimiter
'                       end quote
```

If you're *really* sure that there will always be `search=` followed by the text you want, you can do:

```
$ sed -e 's#.*search=\(.*\)">#&\1</a>#'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No downvote because of the heroic effort, but when one line of code requires 14 lines of explanation, it's probably too clever for the next person to maintain it.

Comment: LOL @Adam: I was assuming that the OP didn't know anything about regular expressions.  That, coupled with making a "robust" pattern resulted in a long explanation.  Oh well, I tried.  Hopefully, he learned *something* (if he didn't get bored 1/3rd of the way down my post that is!). :-)

Comment: When I try to explain something technical at that level of detail, I usually find that I learn something myself - so it's never a wasted effort.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="=" }
{
    o=$NF
    gsub(/\042>/,"",o)
    print $0, o"</a>"

}' file
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Superior Mana Oil"> Superior Mana Oil</a>
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tabard of Brute Force"> Tabard of Brute Force</a>
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tabard of the Wyrmrest Accord"> Tabard of the Wyrmrest Accord</a>
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tattered Hexcloth Sack"> Tattered Hexcloth Sack</a>
```

if you are not good at something, read up the docs. That's always the start to the solution. For learning about awk/gawk, go to the [doc](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/gawk.html).

Answer (score 2):

Nice awk! But

`sed -n 's|=\([^"].*\)">|&\1</a>|p'`

is shorter and will silently remove lines that don't match.

Answer (score 0):

then let's do it in sed.

replace.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tattered Hexcloth Sack">
# =>
#<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Tattered Hexcloth Sack">Tattered Hexcloth Sack</a>
sed -r -e 's|(<a href=".*search=(.*))">|\1">\2</a>|' $1
```

./replace.sh input.txt

Answer (score 0):

Use sed:

```
sed 's/\(.*search=\)\(.*\)\(".*\)/\1\2\3\2<\/a>/' brokenlinks.txt
```