# Linux Text File Manipulation with sed/awk

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have a list in the following format

`77 Infinite Dust

4 Illusion Dust

12 Dream Shard

29 Star's Sorrow`

I need to change this to:

`77 
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Infinite Dust">Infinite Dust</a>

4 
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Illusion Dust">Illusion Dust</a>

12 
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Dream Shard">Dream Shard</a>

29 
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Star's Sorrow">Star's Sorrow</a>`

I've managed to get this list to the right format just missing the numbers by using:

```
sed 's|^[0-9]*.|<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=|g' filename | sed 's|$|">|g' | sed 's#<a[ \t][ \t]*href[ \t]*=[ \t]*".*search=\([^"]*\)">#&\1</a>#'
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to keep the numbers before the list, any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You mention sed and awk in your tags, but there's no reason to avoid perl.  Since you mention linux as well, you're not too concerned about portability, and nearly all the major distributions (if not all) will include a perl interpreter...so why not use it?

Comment: I have no perl experience, I'm sure it does a perfectly good job though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had told us what you were ultimately trying to do in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101004/linux-text-file-manipulation), we would have told you a much easier way to do so.

As I said in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101004/linux-text-file-manipulation/2101061#2101061) to your last question, you can have `sed` remember a part of the pattern, and refer to that part as `\1`, `\2`, etc.

You need to remember the number and the rest of the line separately, so the pattern is: `\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)`: which is basically zero of more digits, followed by space, followed by any number of characters.

So your `sed` command becomes:

```
`sed -e 's|\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)|\1 <a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=\2">\2</a>|'
```

That command does everything you want in one go.

Comment: I actually needed both solutions as the file is split into 2 parts, one containing numbers at the start and the other just containing the item names. Thanks once again for your help though, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with sed by mapping the line parts to groups. in sed groups the A and B in (A)--(B) match to  \1 and \2, with the added wrinkle that the "()" need to be escaped:
e.g.

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\ \(.*\)$/\1 -- \2/g' testfile
```

maps the numbers up to the space to group 1 and everything following to group 2. You can then map group 1 and 2 to whatever you like -, e.g. by changing the sed replacement to something like

```
 \1 <a href.....\2">\2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
{
    s=""
    for(i=2;i<NF;i++) s=s$i
    s=s" "$NF
    printf $1 "<a href=\"http://www.wowhead.com/?search="s
    print "\042>"s"</a>"

} ' file
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
77<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Infinite Dust">Infinite Dust</a>
4<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Illusion Dust">Illusion Dust</a>
12<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Dream Shard">Dream Shard</a>
29<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/?search=Star's Sorrow">Star's Sorrow</a>
```

Comment: just need a space after the digits.

Answer (score 0):

With awk it would be something like:

```
{  
   rest = substr($0, length($1)+2, length($0));
   printf("%d <a href=\"http://www.wowhead.com/?search=%s\">%s</a>\n", $1, rest, rest); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In sed, you can use the & character to place the matched pattern in the replacement text.  For example:

echo xyz | sed 's/^xyz/abc &/'

would output

abc xyz

So in your example,

sed 's|^[0-9]*.|& <a href ....